# Gracefully nested classes in PHP - Any suggest?

Tags: php, class, nested-class

I got a way to define nested classes in Php, but it is pretty raw.

```
class foo {

  function define_new_class($class, $code) {
    if (!class_exists($class)) {
      $definition = eval($code);
    }
  }

  function bar() {
    $new_class = "boo";
    $this->define_new_class($new_class, "class $new_class {}");
    $obj = new $new_class();

    echo "Current class: " . get_class($this) . "\n"; // foo
    echo "\$obj class: " . get_class($obj) . "\n"; // boo
  }
}

$foo = new foo();
$foo->bar();
```

Is it possible to do the same job in a gracefully way?

Comment: Nested classes... Makes no sense whatsoever. Can you add an example explaining why you think you need to do this?

Comment: Creating dynamic classes is... iffy. If you (a) know what that class should do and (b) know how to do it, you are _far_ better of writing an _actual_ configurable class which does exactly that when configured correctly. What problem are you trying to solve with these dynamic classes? I would bet a lot on there being a better way. Otherwise, maintaining an debugging becomes a terrible, terrible nightmare.

Comment: I had to define one and only one class to manage many custom objects which type should not be `stdClass`. Applying this way I can read clearly the code on debugging mode and I know actually what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no way to define a true nested classes:
instead of use a nested class you can create another class that starts with the name of OuterClass:

```
class OuterClass {
   ...stufs...
}
class OuterClass_InnerClass {
   ...stufs...
}
```

or use namespaces

```
class OuterClass {
   ...stufs...
}
class \OuterClass\InnerClass {
   ...stufs...
}
```